# OpenCV Matching Exposure across images

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing

I was wondering if its possible to match the exposure across a set of images.

For example, lets say you have 5 images that were taken at different angles. Images 1-3,5 are taken with the same exposure whilst the 4th image have a slightly darker exposure. When I then try to combine these into a cylindrical panorama using (`seamFinder with: gc_color`, `surf detection`, `MULTI_BAND blending`,`Wave correction`, etc.) the result turns out with a big shadow in the middle due to the darkness from image 4.

I've also tried using `exposureCompensator` without luck.

Since I'm taking the pictures in iOS, I maybe could increase exposure manually when needed? But this doesn't seem optimal..

Have anyone else dealt with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This method is probably overkill (and not just a little) but the current state-of-the-art method for ensuring color consistency between different images is presented in [this article](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~yoavhacohen/color-consistency/color-consistency-light.pdf) from HaCohen *et al.*

Their algorithm can correct a wide range of errors in image sets. I have implemented and tested it on datasets with large errors and it performs very well.

But, once again, I suppose this is way overkill for panorama stitching.

Comment: Can you share your implementation?

Comment: How is it overkill? Seems like the perfect solution in my opinion. Would be great if you could share that implementation :)

Comment: @Filip  I'm sorry, I implemented this in a specific context ([photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry) datasets to be precise) with some modifications of my own. That wouldn't help you for your panorama.

Comment: @taarraas Unfortunately, I wrote this code while working in a company. I can't very well disclose it. However, I would be glad to point you towards the right tools for some of the steps of their algorithm (quadratic optimization especially)

Comment: Sure, that'd be great. @Sunreef

Comment: @Filip I didn't implement their first part about matching pixels together since I obtained this information with another method. However, for the different quadratic optimization problems they define, what you will need is an efficient Sparse Quadratic Programming Solver. Since I code in C++, I used [Ceres-solver](http://ceres-solver.org/) built with  [SuiteSparse](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html). I don't  really know about such tools on iOS.

Comment: Link to paper is broken.. what paper is this? I’m guessing it’s Y. HaCohen, E. Shechtman, D. B. Goldman, and D. Lischinski. Op- timizing color consistency in photo collections. ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG), 32(4), 2013.

Answer (score 2):

[Sunreef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5198595/sunreef) has provided a very good paper, but it does seem overkill because of the complexity of a possible implementation.

What you want to do is to equalize the exposure not on the entire images, but on the overlapping zones. If the histograms of the overlapped zones match, it is a good indicator that the images have similar brightness and exposure conditions. Since you are doing more than 1 stitch, you may require a global equalization in order to make all the images look similar, and then only equalize them using either a weighted equalization on the overlapped region or a quadratic optimiser (which is again overkill if you are not a professional photographer). OpenCV has a simple implmentation of a simple equalization compensation algorithm.

The `detail::`[ExposureCompensator](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/stitching/doc/exposure_compensation.html#detail::ExposureCompensator) class of OpenCV  (sample implementation of such a stitiching is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp)) would be ideal for you to use.

1. Just create a compensator (try the 2 different types of compensation: `GAIN` and `GAIN_BLOCKS`)
2. Feed the images into the compensator, based on where their top-left cornes lie (in the stitched image) along with a mask (which can be either completely white or white only in the overlapped region).
3. Apply compensation on each individual image and iteratively check the results.

I don't know any way to do this in iOS, just OpenCV.

Comment: Have you tried the `ExposureCompensator`? Did it work for you? My images still look pretty unbalanced.

Comment: Yes, ExposureCompensator with GainBlocks works good for me, but I used it only for 2 stitches.